# Java - XML NodeList.item() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

When I'm parsing Android XML layouts with SAXParser and reading element items thru NodeList, I get NPE

```
NodeList list = e.getChildNodes(); // e is Element
for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = list.item(i);
    if(node == null) {
        continue;
    }
    if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        // process somehow it
    }
}
```

Layout XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@id/dbx_button_container" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <include android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:id="@id/dbx_button_bar" android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/bottom_bar_light" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@id/dbx_main_container" android:background="@color/lightBlueBackground" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@id/dbx_button_container">
        <TextView android:textSize="@dimen/dbx_action_bar_title_text_size" android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@id/dbx_install_title" android:background="@color/actionBarBackground" android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/dbx_action_bar_default_height" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tab_dropbox" android:drawablePadding="3.0dip" />
        <View android:id="@id/dbx_separator" android:background="#ff000000" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip" />
        <View android:id="@id/dbx_top_space" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip" android:layout_weight="7.0" />
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/dbx_icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon_new" android:layout_weight="7.0" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@id/dbx_install_main" android:paddingLeft="30.0dip" android:paddingRight="30.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip" />
            <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:textSize="12.0sp" android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@id/dbx_install_sub" android:paddingLeft="30.0dip" android:paddingRight="30.0dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.25" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:id="@id/dbx_bottom_space" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip" android:layout_weight="10.0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I read all inner elements recursively and suddenly get NPE:

```
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.nodeListItem(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.item(Unknown Source)
```

So why it happens? How to avoid this exception and just read the elements data?

UPD:
Sometimes NPE is thrown in getLength():

```
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.nodeListGetLength(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.getLength(Unknown Source)
```

UPD 2:
Entire body

```
public List<DomElement> getChildNodes() {
    ArrayList<DomElement> elements = new ArrayList<DomElement>();
    NodeList list = e.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = list.item(i);
        if(node == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            elements.add(new DomElement(doc, element));
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Seems very weird that you're getting errors on **DOM** objects if you're using a **SAX** parser.

Comment: Assuming you're actually using a **DOM** parser and your listed code is navigating the DOM tree, does the `// process somehow it` code perhaps modify the DOM tree while iterating the `NodeList`?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything. I have a class that is wrapper around Element. It provides prettier interfaces for my purposes. The method I sent is actually reads inner DOM elements (I added full code to the first messages)

Comment: I have the exact same issue. The strange tink is that when I evaluate the exact same expression that throws in the Intellij debugger (when I catch it and have a breakpoint on the printstacktrace) it always works.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the below link.

https://www.davidpashley.com/2016/01/18/nullpointerexceptions-in-xerces-j/

Summary from the article:

> Xerces is not thread-safe. ParentNode caches iterations through the
> NodeList of children to speed up performance and stores them in the
> Node’s Document object. In multi-threaded applications, this can lead
> to race conditions and NullPointerExceptions.  And because it’s a
> threading issue, the problem is intermittent and hard to track down.
>
> The solution is to synchronise your code on the DOM, and this means
> the Document object, everywhere you access the nodes. I’m not certain
> exactly which methods need to be protected, but I believe it needs to
> be at least any function that will iterate a NodeList. I would start
> by protecting every access and testing performance, and removing some
> if needed.
>
> Notice the “synchronized ( m_element.getOwnerDocument()) {}” block
> around the section that deals with the DOM. The NPE would normally be
> thrown on the nl.getLength() or nl.item() calls.

Comment: Very informative !